# Remove menu button from Iframe

Tags: html, typescript, iframe

How should I do to remove these 2 buttons ? I can't find any properties to set them to false:
[image]
[image]

For now this is my code:

```
      <iframe
        [src]="item1?.downloadURL | safe"
        class="center"
        frameborder="0"
        controlsList="nodownload"
        allowfullscreen
      >
      </iframe>
```

Comment: What kind of iframe is it? Youtube?

Comment: Hi, I thought it was the same for everyone. I am using api.video iframe : https://docs.api.video/docs/video-playback-features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the player controls.

controls parameter type definition:

type ControlName = "play" | "seekBackward" | "seekForward" | "playbackRate"
| "volume" | "fullscreen" | "subtitles" | "chapters"
| "pictureInPicture" | "progressBar" | "chromecast" | "download" | "more";
If no value is provided for the "controls" parameter, all controls will be hidden.

Note: the only control that can still be visible is the unmute button if the video as started muted. To hide all controls, including this one, use the setChromeless() method

### Example:

**player.hideControls();**

If a list of control names if provided, the associated controls will be hidden.

### Example:

```
    player.showControls();                          // display all controls ...
    player.hideControls(["download", "subtitles"]); // ... except "download" and "subtitles"
```

heres the [link](https://docs.api.video/docs/video-player-sdk#:%7E:text=Unmute%20the%20video.-,hideControls(controls%3F%3A%20ControlName%5B%5D),-Hide%20the%20player) to the article